# MemcacheService increment issue with latest GAE SDK version (1.9.26)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

After updating to latest GAE SDK version 1.9.26, my ShardedCounter code stopped working and started throwing:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.memoizedSize
>   from class
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb$MemcacheIncrementRequest

With this code:

```
   public final void increment() {
       // Find how many shards are in this counter.
       int numShards = getShardCount();
       // Choose the shard randomly from the available shards.
       long shardNum = generator.nextInt(numShards);
       Key shardKey = KeyFactory.createKey(kind, Long.toString(shardNum));
       incrementPropertyTx(shardKey, CounterShard.COUNT, 1, 1);
       mc.increment(kind, 1); // here
   }
```

Comment: Using version 1.9.18 everything works fine.

Comment: As this started when you changed version I would recommend opening a Issue Tracker here[1]. Be sure to include a minimal working example project showing the issue.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry